# Android studio - rotation animation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

'I'm working on a project for Uni in Android Studio and I'm trying to make a planet rotate. The planet goes beyond the borders of the phone on the left and right side and it is centered. When I start the animation the image with the planet misses the parts that go beyond the borders of the phone and I think I need to resize the image to be larger than the phone itself but I can't understand how so please help me. I've had only 3 classes about Android programming so far but I wanted to study more on my own.'

in the mainactivity.xml I have this

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="732dp"
            android:animation="@anim/rotate"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/earth"
            android:visibility="visible" />
```